# Linear independent vectors of nilpotent transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, nilpotence

$V$ is a vector space.
$N$ is a nilpotent transformation $N:V\rightarrow V$ such that $N^k=0$ ($k$ is the lowest).
$v \in V$, $v \notin \text{ker}\ N^{k-1}$ (in other words: $N^{k-1}v \ne 0$).

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ be:

$v_1 = v$

$v_2 = Nv_1$

...

$v_k = Nv_{k-1}$

Show that $v_1, v_2,\ldots,v_k$ are linearly independent.

Well I know that $\text{ker}\ N  \in \text{ker}\ N^2 
\in \ldots \text{ker}\ N^{k-2} \in \text{ker}\ N^{k-1}  \in V = N^k$

But how do I continue from here? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I think I know how to solve this actually. You can delete the question

Comment: This site is to benefit anyone, so you shouldn't be deleting your posts while getting an answer.

Comment: I have an answer I can post here but I don't know how to use all the signs (say A={1,2,3}, how do you write the sign of "1 is in A"). Is there a tab I can use all these ?

Comment: Please refer to the following tutorial: [TeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_1,\ldots, a_k\in \Bbb R$ such that
$$a_1v_1+\cdots+a_k v_k=0$$
assume that the coefficients $a_i$ aren't all $0$ and let 
$$p=\min_{1\le i\le k}\{i\;|\; a_i\ne0\}$$
so we have
$$a_{p}v_p+\cdots+a_kv_k=0\tag1$$
Now apply $N^{k-p+1}$ to $(1)$ we get
$$a_p N^{k-p+1}v_p=a_pN^{k-1}v=0$$
and since $N^{k-1}v\ne0$ then $a_p=0$ which's a contradiction. Conclude.

Comment: Another productive day!